# connect website to database on different server

Tags: asp.net, database, web-config

There are 2 servers. Server A and Server B. My website is on Server A and my database is on server B. How can I let my website connect to server B's database in asp.net (C#)?
I think it should be set in web.config file. Assume the ip address on server B is 123.45.678.90 and my domain on server A is www.example.com (Will mssql.example.com be useful?)

Comment: Check this out: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server on Server B must allow Remote Connections and the TCP/IP protocol must be enabled and listing to the IP address of Server B. Then you can connect from Server A using the ip address of domain name.

Configure the protocols through the SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (Assuming you have MSSQLSERVER instance)

[image]

Enable remote connections by connecting with SQL Server Management studio to the database and ask the properties of the Instance and go to 'Connections' there is an option ' Allow remote connections to this server'

[image]

Don't forget at last to check your firewall for port 1433. The connection string can be put in the web.config e.q.:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=ip-address;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And in the C# Code the connection string can be accessed by using:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: In case of SQLEXPRESS you can download the Management Studio from Microsoft the only different thing is that the connectionString in the webconfig must and with \SQLEXPRESS after the IP e.q. 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a connection string that points to that database.  Here's an example on how to build one using an IP:  http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connect-via-an-ip-address/

Here's instructions on how to place that string into your config file and read that into your code:  http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/

These connection strings can then be used to run the SQL you need (for instance, creating an SqlConnection object and running commands with SqlCommand objects) like here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10351647/70471

Comment: Hi @Paul Zaczowski, Thanks for your answer but it is not working for me. I created the string `<add name="serverBdatabase" connectionString="server=123.45.678.90; Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;database=databaseName; uid=userID; password=******; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>` and I used dataset.xsd to make a tableAdapter. It could not connect to database even...